# Google Spreadsheet: ArrayFormula and Filter

Tags: google-sheets

I realize that there are multiple questions with this title, but I don't understand the answers to them, or it is not directly related to my issue.

I'm trying to avoid manually "dragging" a formula to duplicate it for each row.

Formula looks like this

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A6), 
    "", 
    COUNT(FILTER(Data!C$2:C, 
                 Data!A$2:A = A6, 
                 Data!B$2:B >= B$2, 
                 Data!B$2:B <= B$3, 
                 Data!C$2:C >= E$3, 
                 Data!C$2:C <= E$2)))
```

I'm not sure all the anchors are needed when using `ARRAYFORMULA`.

The `A` column is the one I want to "interate", the rest of the ranges should evaluate to whatever they're evaluating to now.

I have tried this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A6:A), 
              "", 
              COUNT(FILTER(Data!C$2:C, 
                           Data!A$2:A = A6:A, 
                           Data!B$2:B >= B$2, 
                           Data!B$2:B <= B$3, 
                           Data!C$2:C >= E$3,
                           Data!C$2:C <= E$2))))
```

In which the `A6:A` seems to evaluate correctly to each cell in the `A` column. However, the ranges from the `Data` sheet also seem to evaluate to a single value and not the ranges.

Am I missing something or do I not understand how `ARRAYFORMULA` works?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29203247/using-countifs-in-an-array-forumla

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`filter` is an arrayformula by itself → it can't be used in another arrayFormula because Sheets cannot handle array of arrays.

## Workaround

You are looking for `countifs` arrayFormula, which is solved with `mmult`:

`=arrayformula(TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE((Data!B$2:B>=B2)*(Data!B$2:B<=B3)*(Data!C$2:C<=E2)*(Data!C$2:C>=E3)),--(Data!A$2:A=TRANSPOSE(A6:A10)))))`

---

## Explanation

`=arrayformula(TRANSPOSE(MMULT(...,...)
                         ^^^^^  mmult will count for 1's and 0's in intersection
                                of conditions`

`...TRANSPOSE((Data!B$2:B>=B2)*(Data!B$2:B<=B3)*(Data!C$2:C<=E2)*(Data!C$2:C>=E3))...
              ^^^^ any number of 'plain' conditions goes here`

`...--(Data!A$2:A=TRANSPOSE(A6:A10)...
       ^^^^ all 'filter' conditions go here, you have only 1 of those`

Comment: What does '--' do and is it required? It's reminiscent of an SQL comment.

Comment: `--` converts boolean true/false into 1/0. `mmult` function uses numbers, not booleans. The other way is to multiply by 1 (`*1`) or add 0 (`+1`)