# How to add a query with where date condition in a arrayformula?

Tags: date, google-sheets, array-formulas

I need to add a query in arrayformula.
My data:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DATE | ITEM | TRANSACTION | PRICE | QTY | ARRAYFORMULA??? |
| 2 | 2021/06/30 | aaaa | verify | 14.00 | 1 | 74.00 ((5-0)*14+4) |
| 3 | 2021/06/30 | bbbb | verify | 10.00 | 1 | 202.00 ((40-20)*10+2) |
| 4 | 2021/06/30 | bbbb | sell | 15.00 | 20 | - |
| 5 | 2021/06/10 | aaaa | received | 4.00 | 1 | - |
| 6 | 2021/05/31 | aaaa | verify | 10.00 | 1 | 50.00 ((5-0)*10+0) |
| 7 | 2021/05/31 | bbbb | verify | 8.00 | 1 | 322.00 ((40-0)*8+2) |
| 8 | 2021/05/20 | bbbb | received | 2.00 | 1 | - |
| 9 | 2021/05/10 | bbbb | buy | 8.00 | 40 | - |
| 10 | 2021/05/09 | aaaa | buy | 11.00 | 5 | - |

Basically I need in column F: if transaction is "verify",  **return the value received for that item PLUS the PRODUCT between the quantity in stock** (column E where column C is "buy" MINUS column E where column C is "sell") **and the current price** (column D) **until that date**.
I think I need 3 queries: one for received values, another for quantity bought and the last for quantity sold. I'm stuck in the first query:

=SUM(QUERY(A2:E;"SELECT SUM(D) WHERE A <= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE(A2);"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND C = 'received' AND B = '"&B2&"'"))

Another approach:

=vlookup(B2;QUERY(A2:E;"SELECT B, SUM(D) WHERE A <= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE(A2);"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND C = 'received' AND B = '"&B2&"' group by B");2;false)+(vlookup(B2;QUERY(A2:E;"SELECT B, SUM(E) WHERE A <= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE(A2);"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND C = 'buy' AND B = '"&B2&"' group by B");2;false)-iferror(vlookup(B2;QUERY(A2:E;"SELECT B, SUM(E) WHERE A <= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE(A2);"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND C = 'sell' AND B = '"&B2&"' group by B");2;false);0))*D2

I can't add this in a arrayformula (cell F1). Btw I need a arrayformula because I have a lot of data.
Sorry my English. Thanks for your help!

Comment: what date you have in A2?

Comment: ArrayFormula cannot be used to execute multiple querys as each single query already returns an array, not a single value. You would need to either 1. use AutoFill to fill out each row, or 2. restructure your formula to do the same thing as query but without using QUERY. Reference: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/97310/how-to-use-arrayformula-with-query-in-google-sheets

Comment: @CarlosM I've seen this before, but I need to filter dates. I don't know how to use vlookup(...&...&...) filtering values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Max Makhrov posted an answer is this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598177/google-spreadsheet-arrayformula-and-filter) using "MMULT(TRANSPOSE(" to FILTER in ARRAYFORMULA. I solved my question with the below arrayformula ([link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNYAk.jpg)):

```
={"ARRAYFORMULA";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C2:C<>"verify";"";MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(A2:A)<=A2:A)*(TRANSPOSE(B2:B)=B2:B)*(TRANSPOSE(C2:C)="received");if(D2:D="";0;D2:D))+if(D2:D="";0;D2:D)*(MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(A2:A)<=A2:A)*(TRANSPOSE(B2:B)=B2:B)*(TRANSPOSE(C2:C)="buy");if(E2:E="";0;E2:E))-MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(A2:A)<=A2:A)*(TRANSPOSE(B2:B)=B2:B)*(TRANSPOSE(C2:C)="sell");if(E2:E="";0;E2:E)))))}
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
={"ARRAYFORMULA"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA((VLOOKUP(COUNTIFS(C2:C, C2:C, C2:C, "verify", ROW(C2:C), "<="&ROW(C2:C))&"♦"&B2:B&"♦buy", QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IFERROR(SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(C:C, "verify"))&"♦"&VLOOKUP(
IF(SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(C:C, "verify"), COUNTA(C:C))-(SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(C:C, "verify"), 1, 0)*COUNTA(C:C))>FILTER(ROW(A:A), C:C="verify"), SEQUENCE(1, COUNTA(C:C)), )&FILTER(B:B, C:C="verify"), 
{ROW(A:A)&B:B, B:B&"♦"&C:C&"×"&D:D&"×"&E:E}, 2, 0))), "×"), "select Col1,sum(Col2),sum(Col3) where Col2 is not null group by Col1"), 3, 0)-
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(COUNTIFS(C2:C, C2:C, C2:C, "verify", ROW(C2:C), "<="&ROW(C2:C))&"♦"&B2:B&"♦sell", QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IFERROR(SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(C:C, "verify"))&"♦"&VLOOKUP(
IF(SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(C:C, "verify"), COUNTA(C:C))-(SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(C:C, "verify"), 1, 0)*COUNTA(C:C))>FILTER(ROW(A:A), C:C="verify"), SEQUENCE(1, COUNTA(C:C)), )&FILTER(B:B, C:C="verify"), 
{ROW(A:A)&B:B, B:B&"♦"&C:C&"×"&D:D&"×"&E:E}, 2, 0))), "×"), "select Col1,sum(Col2),sum(Col3) where Col2 is not null group by Col1"), 3, 0), 0))*
 IF(C2:C="verify", D2:D, )+
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(COUNTIFS(C2:C, C2:C, C2:C, "verify", ROW(C2:C), "<="&ROW(C2:C))&"♦"&B2:B&"♦received", QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IFERROR(SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(C:C, "verify"))&"♦"&VLOOKUP(
IF(SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(C:C, "verify"), COUNTA(C:C))-(SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(C:C, "verify"), 1, 0)*COUNTA(C:C))>FILTER(ROW(A:A), C:C="verify"), SEQUENCE(1, COUNTA(C:C)), )&FILTER(B:B, C:C="verify"), 
{ROW(A:A)&B:B, B:B&"♦"&C:C&"×"&D:D&"×"&E:E}, 2, 0))), "×"), "select Col1,sum(Col2),sum(Col3) where Col2 is not null group by Col1"), 2, 0), 0)))}
```

[image]

---

non-english locale:

```
={"ARRAYFORMULA"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA((VLOOKUP(COUNTIFS(C2:C; C2:C; C2:C; "verify"; ROW(C2:C); "<="&ROW(C2:C))&"♦"&B2:B&"♦buy"; QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IFERROR(SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(C:C; "verify"))&"♦"&VLOOKUP(
IF(SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(C:C; "verify"); COUNTA(C:C))-(SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(C:C; "verify"); 1; 0)*COUNTA(C:C))>FILTER(ROW(A:A); C:C="verify"); SEQUENCE(1; COUNTA(C:C)); )&FILTER(B:B; C:C="verify"); 
{ROW(A:A)&B:B\ B:B&"♦"&C:C&"×"&D:D&"×"&E:E}; 2; 0))); "×"); "select Col1,sum(Col2),sum(Col3) where Col2 is not null group by Col1"); 3; 0)-
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(COUNTIFS(C2:C; C2:C; C2:C; "verify"; ROW(C2:C); "<="&ROW(C2:C))&"♦"&B2:B&"♦sell"; QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IFERROR(SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(C:C; "verify"))&"♦"&VLOOKUP(
IF(SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(C:C; "verify"); COUNTA(C:C))-(SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(C:C; "verify"); 1; 0)*COUNTA(C:C))>FILTER(ROW(A:A); C:C="verify"); SEQUENCE(1; COUNTA(C:C)); )&FILTER(B:B; C:C="verify"); 
{ROW(A:A)&B:B\ B:B&"♦"&C:C&"×"&D:D&"×"&E:E}; 2; 0))); "×"); "select Col1,sum(Col2),sum(Col3) where Col2 is not null group by Col1"); 3; 0); 0))*
 IF(C2:C="verify"; D2:D; )+
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(COUNTIFS(C2:C; C2:C; C2:C; "verify"; ROW(C2:C); "<="&ROW(C2:C))&"♦"&B2:B&"♦received"; QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IFERROR(SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(C:C; "verify"))&"♦"&VLOOKUP(
IF(SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(C:C; "verify"); COUNTA(C:C))-(SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(C:C; "verify"); 1; 0)*COUNTA(C:C))>FILTER(ROW(A:A); C:C="verify"); SEQUENCE(1; COUNTA(C:C)); )&FILTER(B:B; C:C="verify"); 
{ROW(A:A)&B:B\ B:B&"♦"&C:C&"×"&D:D&"×"&E:E}; 2; 0))); "×"); "select Col1,sum(Col2),sum(Col3) where Col2 is not null group by Col1"); 2; 0); 0)))}
```

Comment: I don't know why, but it doesn't work. I replaced all "," with ";" (except in queries) because of my language. [link](https://imgur.com/Wq9eH3f)

Comment: Almost... I notice that the formula does not include a line with a transaction other than "verify" above another line with a "verify" transaction (both with the same date). [link](https://imgur.com/KHapxlo) In this case, I expectec 402 istead of 322. In that day, I bought 10 more units of "bbbb" for $7, but the "real" value was $8. To solve this I would need to manually change the rows... Thaks for your help!