# Arrayformula with countif in google sheets to count duplicates until current row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to count the duplicates only until the current row. And I need it to be in an arrayformula as I need it to expand automatically when a new row is added

In excel I would use a table with a function looking something like:

`=COUNTIF($A$2:A2,B2)` -> in cell C2

In cell C10 the function would automatically become:

`=COUNTIF($A$2:A10,B10)`

I am not able to perform this action in google sheets:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(J:J)=1,"Column title", IF(ISBLANK(J:J),"",COUNTIF($J$1:J1,J:J))))
```

I know that `$J$1:J1` won't work but am out of ideas.

Is this somehow achievable?

Comment: It is achievable, can you mock up, and share via link (preferably editable) an example to demonstrate the solution, to be sure I'm understanding the question correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A:A="","",countifs(A:A,A:A,row(A:A),"<="&row(A:A))))
```

[image]