# Retrieving redirected URLs in Google Sheets using script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Having some issues with retrieving redirected URLs on Google Sheets here.

cell A1: 6962110916490185986

cell B1: =getRedirect(CONCATENATE("https://t.tiktok.com/i18n/share/video/",A1)

Expected results: https://www.tiktok.com/@hoaa.hanassii/video/6962110916490185986?

Actual results: https://t.tiktok.com/i18n/share/video/6962110916490185986

script:

```
function getRedirect(url) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,{'followRedirects': false, 'muteHttpExceptions': false});
  var redirectUrl = response.getHeaders()['Location'];
  var responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
  if (redirectUrl) {
    var nextRedirectUrl = getRedirect(redirectUrl);
    Logger.log(url + " is redirecting to " + redirectUrl + ". (" + responseCode + ")");
    return nextRedirectUrl;
  }
  else {
    Logger.log(url + " is canonical. (" + responseCode + ")");
    return url;
  }
}
```

Comment: Issue seems to be similar with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68653443/retrieving-redirected-urls-in-google-sheets-using-script). Where editor and custom function has different result. (I run your script via editor and the url is redirecting, while custom function does not). You might want to consider using custom menu instead of custom function to get your redirected url.

Comment: You might also want to file a ticket in issuetracker.google.com

Comment: Hey @RonM , tried changing it to run via custom menu. Still doesn't work. Not sure how else I should go about this at the moment. Thanks for your suggestion though, happy to try other methods as well.

Comment: Can you share how did you do it via custom menu? I was thinking of suggesting a way but I need your insights on how it should be done such as is this base url fix? or you plan on having an option to change this `https://t.tiktok.com/i18n/share/video/` and your column a will always contain a video id or something? Please share how you did it using a custom menu so i could help debugging

Comment: @RonM literally just added the function of onOpen() section as shown here (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) first in the script, followed up by the exact same script up there. Still doesn't run as what I had in mind. Not sure if this was what you meant by "using custom menu instead of custom function". Happy to get on a Zoom to walkthrough and solve this.

Comment: @RonM yes, column A will always have an ID. What I'm trying to get, ultimately, is just the "@hoaa.hanassii" of the expected URL result. The follow-up formula from the above was to use MID() to get just the "@XXXXX"s.

Comment: I was thinking to provide a solution where column A contains your vid id, column B contains your concatenated url and column C contains the result (@hoaaa.hanassiil) triggered when clicking the custom menu. Would that fit your preference?

Comment: @RonM sure thing, that works too i guess. Will probably optimize it down the road but at least it should be better than how it is now.

Comment: Ok, ill try to come up with a solution

Comment: Thanks @RonM! Let me know if you need any other details. Chat function here isn't open up to me for now as I'm still a new user. I'm more than happy to take this outside of here if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the earlier comments, using custom menu could achieve the same results when run in script editor which successfully redirects the url being fetched.

### Sample Code:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('ParseRedirectUrl', 'ParseRedirectUrl')
      .addToUi();
}


function ParseRedirectUrl(){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var urlList = sheet.getRange("B1:B").getDisplayValues().flat().filter(String);
  Logger.log(urlList);
  urlList.forEach( (url, index) =>{

    var redirectUrl = getRedirect(url);
    var result = redirectUrl.split('/');
  
    //Write the value in column C. Note that the urlList starts at row 1.
    Logger.log(result);
    sheet.getRange(1+index,3).setValue(result[3]);
  });
}
```

### Sample Input Sheet:

[image]

Formula in B1: `="https://t.tiktok.com/i18n/share/video/"&A1`

### What the code does?

1. Get all urls in column B. Use `Array.flat()` to convert 2-d array to 1-d array. Then use `Array.filter()` to remove empty cells.
2. Loop each url and get its redirected url.
3. Split the redirected url using `Array.split()` with splitter '/' to obtain the user name in the redirected url
4. Write the user name obtained in step 3 to the same row but in column C.

Note:

- You can use your `MID()` in step 3 to obtain the user name.

### Output:

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if you encountered some issues so i could update accordingly

Comment: the script works great! Thank you so much for this. Now I'll try to figure out if it's possible to omit to have to input the formula in B1 at all. Or at least have the formula in B1 to auto-populate when there's a value in A1 without any step from the user.

Comment: You can use this formula to cell `B1` to auto-populate the url when there is a value in column A `=arrayformula(if(A1:A<>"","https://t.tiktok.com/i18n/share/video/"&A1:A,""))`. Don't forget to delete existing values in column B first so that the arrayformula() could write on column B

Comment: Thanks @RonM! Could I trouble you to troubleshoot this =ARRAYFORMULA() formula? `=arrayformula(IF($B2:B="","<--- Please insert TikTok video's URL",IF(COUNTIF($B2:B,"*/video/*"),MID($B2:B,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE($B2:B,"/","~",5))+1,19),IFERROR(MID(getRedirect($B2:B),FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(getRedirect($B2:B),"/","~",6))+1,19),"<--- error in URL"))))` where B2:B are URLs. It keeps throwing out  `#VALUE!`

Comment: Please share a sample sheet with your expected output

Comment: Here you go - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rJKm5KIT8itZs2AC0wdDZ-CGar4mERu4jzJ3mN7KMb8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Oh sorry, it seems countif() doesn't work with arrayformula() as referred to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29203247/using-countifs-in-an-array-formula). I suggest you post a new thread for this question so that other users could also provide solutions in your problem. Rest assure i will try my best to look for a solution as well its just that sheets formula is not my strong points :)

Comment: It seems it is not possible for you to use arrayformula since your getRedirect() don't have the functionality to return an array value (if you will try arrayformula(getRedirect(B2:B)) it will return tiktok.com. but when used as getRedirect(B2) it can return a redirected url)

Comment: Ah, I see. Alrighty, so should I still post a new thread for this issue then? @RonM

Comment: yes, please include in your post that you are using a custom formula as well so that they will be aware

Comment: Alrighty! Thank you so much @RonM. Let me know if you've got an eWallet or something. You've been a great help!

Comment: Hi @RonM ! Someone answered to modify the script as per https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#optimization . But I'm not sure how to go about modifying it properly, unfortunately. Am hoping you would have better luck with this.

Comment: Hi I forgot to tell you, I tried to modify the script to accept an array and return an array but still it is not working with arrayformula

Comment: Ah, I see. Oh well. I've notified @idfurw on his this suggestion in the other thread. Much thanks!