# Trying to apply Array formula in google sheet but it's not working I don't know the reason of the error

Tags: google-sheets

```
=IF(COUNTIFS('Export Data'!D:D,B4,'Export Data'!G:G,$AH$2,'Export Data'!H:H,"Normal Sign")=0,"",COUNTIFS('Export Data'!D:D,B4,'Export Data'!G:G,$AH$2,'Export Data'!H:H,"Normal Sign"))
```

I want to apply array formula for this I tried many different sequences but not working.

As I mentioned the formula shown above, I need to add Array to this formula so I don't need to drag it all the way down in the columns.

Please check this and let me know how can I add the Array formula to this?

Comment: Use `MAP()` or `BYROW()` function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using COUNTIFS in an array formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29203247/using-countifs-in-an-array-formula)